# Monotouch 3.99: Missing Usings in designer files?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

Monotouch 3.99.13

When I edit a XIB in Interface Builder, Monotouch fails to add all the Usings to the designer.cs files it generates. There are no partial clsses made.

[image]

Here's a code snip (notice no usings):

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  <autogenerated>
//      This code was generated by a tool.
//      Mono Runtime Version: 2.0.50727.1433
// 
//      Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if 
//      the code is regenerated.
//  </autogenerated>
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace General {


    // Base type probably should be MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject or subclass
    [MonoTouch.Foundation.Register("AppDelegateIPad")]
    public partial class AppDelegateIPad {

        private UIWindow __mt_window;

        #pragma warning disable 0169
        [MonoTouch.Foundation.Connect("window")]
        private UIWindow window {
            get {
                this.__mt_window = ((UIWindow)(this.GetNativeField("window")));
                return this.__mt_window;
            }
            set {
                this.__mt_window = value;
                this.SetNativeField("window", value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's actually the question?

Comment: "Is this a bug". See below for answers from the Monotouch architects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone has filed this as a bug in the latest MonoDevelop [here](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=683616).  Is that you?  As far as I can tell MonoDevelop has never generated using statements in designer files.

Comment: Yes, I did submit that. There are no other partial classes generated though. Just the XIB and under it the designer.cs I used the template to create the Universal app.

Comment: You can just add a new class called AppDelegateIpad, which you would need to do to implement the AppDelegate logic anyways, and add the usings there.  Not sure why it didn't automatically do that tho, you should update the bug with the additional information.

Comment: I stand corrected, usings are locally scoped and cannot go across partials, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I have updated the bug to request that partials be added to the app delegate in universal projects.